# Need image to retain specific height in mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have picked up development on a site using Visual Composer in a Wordpress theme (Jupiter). On most pages there is a full width row with an image that maxes out at 1600px wide. The client doesnt like how small the photo shrinks as the browser window/mobile reposnse gets smaller.

http://spiderman.ephronsystems.com/full-width-tester/

I added this CSS in a mediaquery:

```
div.vc_single_image-wrapper.vc_box_border_grey {overflow:hidden;}
img.vc_single_image-img.attachment-full {height: 200px;width:auto;max-width:none;margin:0 auto;}
```

This seems to work pretty well but I would rather the image was centered in the browser window. Anyone know how to fix this? I can also replace the VC coding with straight html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `margin-left: 50%;` and `transform:translateX(-50%);` on the `img` at the following

```
@media (max-width: 736px) {
  .wpb_single_image img {
    height: 200px;
    width:auto;
    max-width:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

query